# Consulta com recursividade EntityFramework disparando exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Ao realizar a consulta com recursividade está ocorrendo uma exception:

```
Equipe.RelatorioRH.Single(x => x.IdRodada == IdRodada)
```

> Os metadados de 'EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-Model' são inválidos. Se estiver depurando um minidespejo, você poderá corrigir o problema coletando um novo minidespejo com heap e avaliando a expressão novamente.   Model.RelatorioRH

Alguém saberia do que se trata? Como resolver isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri o que estava acontecendo.

Um método que chama um segundo método que por sua vez chamava o primeiro novamente.
Isso causava a exception.
Infelizmente o Visual Studio descreveu daquela forma dificultado a entendimento do problema.

Comment: isso não é uma resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Quando você utiliza o método `Single()` e a query não retorna 0 ou mais de 1 registro, ocorre uma exception. Verifique se foi isso que ocorreu.

Se o campo que voce está buscando for uma primary key, você pode utilizar o `Find()`, por exemplo.

Comment: Obrigado pelo resposta. eu descrevi abaixo como resposta a solução que encontrei. Infelizmente o retorno que o IDE deu descrevendo o erro confundiu a interpretação do problema.